# Panels content not displaying on copied site

Tags: views, 6, panels, nodes

I'm prepping to convert a large D6 site to D7, so I've copied everything from the server to my local Mac, something I've done a bazillion times w/o a problem.  Concurrently, I changed my dev environment from MacPorts to Homebrew, using PHP54 and MySQL from Homebrew along with the native Apache (2.2.22) on the Mac.  What I'm running into is that Panels content isn't being displayed at all.  I've tried two other sites of ours, one with Panels and one w/o Panels, and the one w/o Panels displays fine.

On my panels pages (using 6.3.9 of Panels), all of the panes are filled by Views content panes and nodequeues, so here's what I've done:

- checked the nodequeues to make sure they have content (they do),
- edited the view itself to make sure content is being returned (it
  is).
- cleared caches (I actually don't export cache_* table content
- when I get the SQL dump from the server)
- went through all of my Apache and PHP configs to make sure everything is set up the same.

The code I'm using is identical to the server (both git clones), and this exact same site worked fine before I switched to Homebrew.  Any thoughts on what would keep the panels content from being displayed like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your Apache error logs and see what errors are reported when loading the Panels page - this is an essential part of your debugging toolkit.

Are you really using PHP5.4? That is likely to be the issue. http://drupal.org/node/1469736 indicates that the published release of Panels is not PHP5.4 compatible, but the dev release may be.

Comment: As Chris Burgess mentioned, the issue was that I was running PHP 5.4 (something I failed to mention in my original description).  I noticed the errors listed [in this issue](http://drupal.org/node/465332) when I ran update.php, and a quick search found that issue. I installed PHP 5.3, and everything started loading just fine.